# Eliminar la etiqueta "programación" permanentemente

Tags: discusión, solicitud-de-quemado

Ya tenemos dos preguntas con la etiqueta [programación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n). Todas las preguntas en Stack Overflow tienen que ver con programación, y no necesitamos marcar todas las preguntas con la misma etiqueta.

Comment: **Burn it.** With prejudice.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, no es necesario

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo.

Comment: Programación esta bloqueada en SO, lo mismo debería aplicarse aqui. Lease http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/514/41104

Comment: ¿Finalmente se aceptó eliminar la etiqueta? ¿por qué siguen existiendo preguntas recientes con la etiqueta "programación" usada? http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39989/que-se-debe-saber-para-usar-backtracking-y-divide-y-venceras

Comment: Otra similar [tag:programar]

Answer (score 7):

Por supuesto que todo es programación.

¿Podría haber excepciones? Si se decide incorporar más temas en el sitio (por ej. del tipo [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), con lo que no estoy de acuerdo), en todo caso ahí se aplicaría una etiqueta que deje claro que no es de programación.

Para todo el resto, **etiquetar como `programación` es irrelevante**.
Tan irrelevante como etiquetar `pregunta` a una pregunta, o `en-español` para marcar que está escrito en español.

Podría bloquearse, estoy de acuerdo.

Pero pondría énfasis en lo primero: **comencemos por editar borrando la etiqueta cuando la usen**. -Vamos gente, no empecemos a exigirle trabajo a los moderadores en temas que podemos resolver fácilmente. Si se volviera un problema serio, ahí pedimos intervención de moderadores, mientras tanto lo podemos manejar dentro de la comunidad.

Comment: Eliminada [tag:programar] de las preguntas que la tenían. Ojalá no vuelva.

Comment: Para el día de hoy, hay como 35 preguntas con [programacion]. He estado trabajando en quitarlas de esas preguntas, ojalá que el número deje de subir... Ciertamente, como comunidad podemos hacer mucho para ayudar a quitar esta molesta etiqueta :)

Answer (score -6):

En mi opinión, diría que **no**. Y esto es por el simple hecho de que, al no haber sitios específicos que no soporten el concepto original de SO, debería haber etiqueta que clasifiquen el contexto de la pregunta que se quiere hacer.

Ejemplos de etiquetas:

- `administracion-de-sistemas` para los temas de SuperUser.
- `servidores` para los temas de Server Fault.
- `base-de-datos` para los temas de Database Administrator.
- `revisión-de-código` para los temas de Code Review.
- `arquitectura-y-diseño` para los temas de Programmers.
- `programación` para los temas de StackOverflow.
- etc...

Ademas, hacer esta clasificación ayuda hacer una migración de preguntas a los sitios correspondientes a futuro.

Comment: 100% de acuerdo. La etiqueta [tag:programación] sería especialmente útil para estos casos: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109/son-aceptables-las-preguntas-que-en-ingl%C3%A9s-corresponderian-a-programmers-stacke

Comment: La mayoría de las preguntas tendrán que ver con programación. Podemos utilizar etiquetas especiales para otras temas, pero yo creo que no es muy útil marcar 95% de las preguntas con la misma etiqueta.

Comment: @PeterOlson, en ello, coincido contigo. Se debería marcar todo lo que no este relacionado con contexto de `StackOverflow`. Todo lo demás, tendría que estar etiquetado con su correspondiente contexto.

Comment: Me pregunto por qué borraste el post... es válida tu opinión, por más que (al menos 3 hasta ahora) no estén de acuerdo... Los puntos negativos no influyen en tu reputación

Comment: El concepto de voto negativo es por el contenido, no por la persona. Y aqui en el Meta, el -1 también quiere decir "no estoy de acuerdo para nada!". Recuerda, [Meta Is Murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) :D