# ¿Deberíamos quemar la etiqueta [programacion]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Deseo proponer que eliminemos la etiqueta *programación* del sitio.

- Actualmente [hay 25 preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programacion) con esa etiqueta y creo que ninguna sería buscada con ese término.
- No tiene wiki y creo que no tiene sentido crear una.
- Las preguntas con esta etiqueta pueden ser cualquier cosa porque, puej, es SOes y TODO es sobre programación (so pena de ser cerrado).

¿Valdría la pena quemar esa etiqueta? ¿Algo que impida que la usen?

Comment: quemas y a la lista negra....

Comment: Sí, es justo eliminarla. He estado trabajando en quitarla por ahora de donde estaba (y no he sido el único a lo largo del tiempo), pero creo que ya es tiempo de sacarla de una vez por todas.

Comment: Sí vi las ediciones de @DiegoRamirez y recordé las preguntas que me he encontrado también. Suelen ser de novatos que ponen cualquier cosa y esta siempre está ahí a la mano

Comment: De hecho, esto se había propuesto antes, en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/152/254650, pero hace ya mucho de eso.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Listo, el proceso de eliminación de la etiqueta esta completado!.

Estaba intrigado sobre el proceso de quemado así que busque en meta y encontré la publicación [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar las etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2839/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-proceso-para-eliminar-las-etiquetas-quemarlas) y vi 2 cosas.

1. Una solicitud-de-quemado no es más que una propuesta hasta que no reciba por lo menos una puntuación de 20. [...]
2. ¡No empiezen a quitar la etiqueta durante las fases de la "propuesta" y el "detacado"!

Debido a estas 2 cosas pregunté en el chat y @gbianchi me orientó y me sugrió quemar la etique ya que la publicación nunca alcanzará los 20 votos y que esto era aplicado a etiquetas más relevantes o que causaran controversia, así que procedí al quemado.

Muchas gracias a @DiegoRamirez que contribuía con la eliminación de etiquetas mediante ediciones y a @Alfabravo que hizo la publicación :D.

Comment: XD, superó los 20 votos