# ¿Estamos olvidando como funcionan los votos en SO-es?

Tags: discusión, votos

Hace ya bastante tiempo que me voy topando con respuestas y cómo no también con preguntas mal formuladas a las que se les llegan a dar puntos positivos.

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es que aún no fue eliminada la pueden ver en el siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/570887/146637

Y hace una semana si no me equivoco, alguien posteo una pregunta en **SO-es** que en lo personal lo sentí agresiva, la pregunta ya quedó eliminada pero tal vez los usuarios con alta reputación si puedan verla y también recordarla, se encuentra o se encontraba en este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/568692/marikones-de-mierda?noredirect=1#comment1005769_568692

Pero más que la pregunta me llamó la atención un comentario que recibí, ya que mi persona al ver que la publicación recibió un punto a favor dijo lo siguiente:

> ¿Enserio le van a dar un voto positivo?

Por lo cual otro usuario me respondió lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me hizo pensar en que algunos usuarios no saben u olvidan para que sirven los votos en **SO-es** a diferencia de los votos que se dan en **Meta**.

Cito parte del centro de ayuda que brinda SO para el caso de los votos https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

> Emitir un voto positivo a una pregunta o respuesta señala para resto de la comunidad que una publicación es interesante, el autor ha investigado, y es útil; emitir un voto negativo señala lo contrario: que la publicación contiene información errónea, no hay investigación previa, o no consigue comunicar información. Cuanta más gente vote en una publicación, tanto más seguros pueden estar los futuros visitantes acerca de la calidad de la información contenida en la misma – ¡y por supuesto los votos positivos son una magnífica forma de agradecimiento al autor de la publicación por el tiempo y el esfuerzo dedicados para escribirla!

Siempre creí que los votos **positivos** que se dan en *SO-es* son porque una pregunta o respuesta tienen **información útil** e incluso **información valiosa** en varios de los casos y los votos **negativos** se dan porque la respuesta carece de información o simplemente no resuelve el problema.

En el caso de *Meta* tenia entendido que un voto **positivo** se da cuando uno esta a favor de una pregunta o respuesta y un **negativo** cuando se esta en contra, bueno también existen los casos en los que se dan votos por otros motivos en cuestión como en felicitaciones de navidad, año nuevo etc. (Pero esto solo pasa en *Meta*).

El punto es que en **SO-es** en específico los votos a favor no se dan cuando uno esta **de acuerdo** con la pregunta o respuesta si no por la información que ésta tiene.

**¿Es así como funciona o me equivoco?**

Pregunto esto porque en su momento tal vez no le di mucha importancia pero si poco a poco nos llenamos la cabeza de que los votos funcionan igual para *Meta* que para *SO-es* me parece que tendremos preguntas y respuestas que no contribuyen con nada en posiciones que no les corresponden (en los casos que por alguna razón no hayan sido eliminadas) ya que en el centro de ayuda dice lo siguiente:

> Los votos son una parte central de nuestro modelo para proporcionar preguntas y respuestas de calidad; son los votos los que hacen que...
>
> ...el buen contenido ascienda a lo más alto
>
> ...el contenido incorrecto caiga a lo más bajo
>
> ...los usuarios que de forma consistente generan buen contenido acumulen reputación y ganen más privilegios en el sitio

Evitar esto obviamente es imposible pero al menos quisiera tener la certeza de poder corregir a cualquier usuario que piense que en *SO-es* se vota igual que en *Meta*, OJO que no lo digo en mala onda, creo que es bueno ir aprendiendo poco a poco el cómo funciona *SO* para que lo nuevos usuarios no adquieran malas mañas al momento de votar, comentar o responder.

Se agradecen los comentarios.

Comment: Hay tres categorías: respuestas destacables (+1), respuestas (0), y malas respuestas (-1).

Comment: @CandidMoe, vale pero con una pregunta [como ésta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5346/deber%c3%adamos-quemar-la-etiqueta-programacion) en el caso de *Meta*, ¿no cambiaria las categorías a algo así?:  Si (+1), No sabe (0) y No (-1), o también a las categorías: De acuerdo (+1), No sabe (0) y No de acuerdo (-1). Bueno en el caso de *Meta* específicamente creo se podrían dar diferentes casos, pero en el caso de *SO-es* si estoy de acuerdo con las categorías que muestras, incluso me atrevería a decir que en *SO-es* solo se dan éstas tres categorías. ;)

Comment: Entiendo, pero soy ajeno a esa problemática y no puedo compartir tu interés.

Comment: Recuerdo esa pregunta, me impactó tanto que le saqué foto (si quieren la agrego en la publicación, pero dudo que sea relevante a la cuestion, solo se dedica a insultar a la comunidad). Sobre, el comentario que citas "alguno que está de acuerdo con el?" fue más una suposición que otra cosa. Como sabemos, todo es posible. También puede ser que voten sin ver la pregunta, o incluso podría ser una cuenta titere. Sinceramente, no se que pudo haber sido. Como se esto? Por que ese comentario es mio xD

Comment: De todas maneras, creo que la mayoría de la comunidad vota bien. Lo notarás con preguntas sobre tareas que no demuestran esfuerzo por ejemplo. Ten en cuenta que el que tus votos sean visibles es un privilegio que se obtiene con solamente 15 de reputación. Eso lo ganas muy rapidamente con votos positivos y respuestas aceptadas. Por lo que los que recién votan podrían no conocer bien el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @DanteS., si me imaginaba eso de que los usuarios nuevos sean los que realizan este tipo de votos, si recordaba que  el comentario era tuyo XD, solo que no lo mencione porque no le veía sentido agregarlo como una especie de queja solo como un ejemplo jejeje.

Comment: A veces he visto que votan negativo a una **buena respuesta** de una **pregunta no tan buena**, como forma de "castigo por responder" a una pregunta que quizás no valia la pena. Pienso que con el comentario en la pregunta, o el voto de cierre, debería ser suficiente. Me parece que ese fue uno de los motivos por los que -un miembro asiduo- dejó de aportar hace poco tiempo atras.

Comment: Excepto en los casos donde responden preguntas en las que el autor no demuestra que se esforzó.

Comment: Por cierto, te refieres a arkanis???

Comment: Quizá la cosa está pasando más por el lado de no saber la mecánica del sitio que por que voten mal. Frecuentemente usuarios nuevos, creyendo que es un foro, publican respuestas que no "responden" en el sentido que esperamos. Más bien son reacciones.

Comment: Está bien raro lo de los votos. La verdad incluso no se si sea cultural en LATAM o los de habla hispana, etc. Por ejemplo, para que una pregunta mía tenga 3 votos positivos, toma meses. Pero para que tenga 3 votos negativos, toma menos de un día (Y es por tonterías, ya que siempre investigo!). Tengo respuestas (según yo buenas y completas) con cientos o miles de vistos, y menos de 10 votos positivos. Igual y es mi estilo de escribir respuestas. Pero los votos son todo menos "objetivo".

Comment: Esto para decir que no veo que los votos tengan UN sólo uso o UNA sola motivación. Cada cabeza es un mundo y cada persona usa su capacidad de votar como se le de la gana. Yo he tratado de apoyar respuestas no aprobadas (pero buenas) que incluso son mejores que la aprobada. También he notado que es común que sólo se vote no por la calidad de la pregunta (siento que eso de "votar por calidad" es un mito o solo restringido a unas 5 personas), sino porque "como tiene 3 votos, pues que tenga 5", "si tiene 9, entonces que tenga 15", osea, por inercia.

Comment: No sé si exista ya en el sitio o ya se haya hecho, o algo similar, una actividad tipo: "Vamos a usar de tal a tal día para hacer un maratón para votar respuestas de X o Y publicaciones, hacerles recomendaciones si es posible". Algo así como las festividades de los "lupercales".

Comment: @Cuauhtli, te doy la razón en cuanto a que muchas veces hay respuestas mejores que las aceptadas, imagino que también es porque los usuarios que preguntan se conforman con la primera respuesta que les sirva y no se toman la molestia de revisar el porque es la mejor solución para su problema, el votar obviamente siempre y cuando tengas la reputación necesaria es según lo que cada uno piensa, aunque no debería ser así (según yo) porque existen métricas para definir si una respuesta es mínimamente aceptable o simplemente de baja calidad.

Comment: Obviamente si la respuesta que se quiere votar cumple lo mínimo para ser aceptable (me refiero a que no sea solo código, tenga enlaces de documentación en lo posible, etc), pues ya será decisión del usuario que vota, pero en lo que no estoy de acuerdo y es la razón por que realicé [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5446/estamos-olvidando-como-funcionan-los-votos-en-so-es) es porque vi votos positivos en respuestas que ni siquiera se pueden considerar respuestas o preguntas que no son preguntas XD, como bien muestro en algunos ejemplos. Gracias por tu opinión ;)

Comment: Eso a mi me suena a cuentas dobles, con el objetivo de ganar reputacion con el autovoto

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Respuesta breve:**

Sí, en el promedio de usuarios, especialmente nuevos que ni han visto el recorrido ni tampoco han visto los pasos de cómo formular preguntas (esas son más ignoradas que semáforos en paraderos de microbuses).
No, para quienes llevamos tiempo siguiendo los lineamientos.

**Detalles adicionales:**

Llevo prácticamente 7 años en SOes (los cumplo en 4 días) y en todo este tiempo he encontrado una masa de usuarios que realiza preguntas de calidad baja, a tal punto que me animé a describir recomendaciones sobre cómo preguntar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 ¿Cuál es el resultado de ponerles en comentario estas "lecturas sugeridas" (en algunos casos "lecturas obligatorias")? Pues, son poquísimos los que te agradecen las recomendaciones, ergo, mejoran su pregunta e incrementan las chances de obtener respuestas concretas y no solo vistas en la pregunta; de cuando en cuando aparecen usuarios frustrados porque no le dan la respuesta que busca y lo manifiesta desde una variedad de expresiones muy interesantes dependiendo del nivel cultural, educativo y calidad humana; personalmente, entre más insultos veo, mayor compasión trato de generar porque me pregunto cómo les habrá tratado la vida para que esa sea su forma de expresarse.

Para el caso de Alejandro: Esa votación que le han dado a la publicación de ese usuario, tiene un significado particular, analizando desde un punto de vista de "empatía", es muy probable que otro usuario se haya sentido igual, quizás hasta exactamente con la misma frustración de Alejandro. Espero que él y usuarios que tengan un comportamiento similar aprendan a manejar el stress y la frustración, esta industria te puede generar bastante stress cuando tienes poco conocimiento, la parte buena es que se soluciona estudiando y practicando, no es necesario ir a maestría ni doctorado para desarrollar confianza al momento de crear software.

Por otro lado, en el caso de Horacio, recién tiene 11 puntos, no puede comentar hasta después de tener más puntaje de reputación, hay varios usuarios que dejan respuestas que no son respuestas, sino agradecimientos. Se aprecia la buena intención, sin embargo, están rompiendo las reglas y el sentido común del sitio, lo segundo en referencia a que bien claro dice "Tu Respuesta" frente al problema planteado en el apartado "Pregunta", dicho de otro modo y siendo extremadamente lógico, ¿cómo un agradecimiento soluciona un problema de código?.

**¿Qué podemos hacer?**

1. Dejar comentarios guiando a los usuarios sobre cómo utilizar la plataforma.
2. Reportando respuestas que no son respuestas.
3. Conseguir puntos de reputación suficientes para acceder a las herramientas de moderación del sitio y ayudar a moderar.

Comment: Yo pensé lo mismo. El votante posirivo debia de sentirse similar a alejandro

Comment: Entiendo @fredyfx, me abriste un poco más la mente, en realidad si creo que la moderación del sitio es lo único que puede ayudar en estos casos, gracias por tu respuesta. ;)

Comment: Un placer colaborar :D

Answer (score 6):

El problema tiene que ver con el concepto en nuestras culturas de lo que es la reputacion.

Yo he detectado dos tipos de mentalidad, los que se centran en los resultados, y los que se centran en las relaciones.

Nuestras culturas mayormente se centran en las relaciones y eso que notas es un reflejo, meritocracia vs conexiones, utilitarismo vs comunitarismo, etc.

En la cultura mexicana en particular hay una representacion de estas dos formas en una metafora-espectaculo-deporte: la lucha libre; En la lucha libre ves las dos formas de obtener la gloria:

en un "bando" puedes ver a los tecnicos o cientificos

[image: el mistico un luchador tecnico]

y en el otro a los rudos.

[image: mephisto un luchador rudo]

Los primeros se centran en perfeccionar sus habilidades luchisticas de manera sistematica, metodica, sumando una gran cantidad de apredizaje y esfuerzo a su haber cada que pueden de manera parsimoniosa, mientras que los segundos se centran simplemente en obtener la victoria por cualquier medio necesario explotando no solamente su fisico, sino tambien su plano emocional en cada oportunidad.

No puede existir el rudo sin el tecnico, pues al final del dia son dos soluciones distintas a un mismo problema: lidiar con una realidad que nos abruma.

Ya sea que halles que tu energia se renueva en tu interior o en la interaccion social, que tu forma de crecer sea prefeccionando lo que haces com si de un arte se tratara o darle alcance al trabajo de otros ambas cosas forman lo que llamamos experiencia en la vida cotidiana o reputacion en el sitio.

Tu nivel de reputacion depende de la calidad de tus posts, pero tambien de que les haga sentir a los demas;nadie esta obligado a darte flecha arriba solo por poner una buena respuesta ni a votarte negativo si agradeces fuera de contexto (como en una respuesta).

Estas dos maneras de ver y entender el mundo nos permitiran entender de maneras diferentes lo que es util y valioso para cada persona y como podemos hacer mejores respuestas a nivel tecnico y de alcance.

En mi caso particular he experimentado mucho en mis respuestas para tratar de intuir como es la comunidad de SoES, podras hallar respuestas super tecnicas con un exceso de ligas de documentacion pero tambien respuestas con memes y mas orientadas a lo que la gente siente cuando lee la respuesta.

Si aceptas un consejo no solicitado, la mejor manera de cazar una recompensa de reputacion es hacer un poco de ambas, y como ejemplo te muestro esto:

[¿Qué paso puedo tomar para arreglar la advertencia de "Raw use of parameterized class 'Class' "?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/551912/qu%C3%A9-paso-puedo-tomar-para-arreglar-la-advertencia-de-raw-use-of-parameterized)

En el momento en que la vi ya tenia respuestas en las comunidades hermanas de SoEN y SOPort (o como se llame eu non falho portugueish :P) y era practicamente imposible que se otorgara la recompensa ya teniendo dos buenas respuestas en cada comunidad, ambas muy solidas a nivel tecnico.

En mi respuesta para abordar la parte tecnica hable de temas de ingenieria de software para mejorar la solucion y sus ventajas para simplificar el codigo ocultando la complejidad verdadera de la solucion.
Pero la parte extra que en mi opinion fue la que hizo que me otorgaran la recompensa fue.... jugar con su codigo para generar la mayor cantidad de dragones y vacas posibles, es decir, creo que ver como alguien agarra tu codigo, hace bromas (como la de que alguien pudiera confundir un dragon con una vaca) y lo lleva al extremo tecnico de hacer un generador puede despertar en alguien las emociones que muchos nencesitamos para aprender mejor y para decir... ese tipo raro carepapa se merece mi reconocimiento por compartir su conocimiento, pero sobre todo por hacerme el dia, por recordarme que no solo es este un sitio de consulta, sino tambien una comunidad viva.

En suma, lo mejor es que una respuesta sea interesante, erudita (el autor ha investigado), y practica (útil) y votar positivamente por las que veamos que tienen todos estos elementos.

Y por lo tanto de alli se desprende un criterio bueno para votar en contra... que una respuesta contenga información errónea, que no tenga sustento (no hay investigación previa sino que es una opinion), o no consigue comunicar información (  osea pusieron la informacion como un codigo de solucion pero no se esfuerzan lo mas minimo en comunicarse con el otro ser humano del otro lado de la pantalla y dificultando que su respuesta se pueda contrastar con otras).

No todo se resuelve con votos, pero el voto responsable en esta comunidad es la herramienta social con la que se premia o castiga a sus integrantes. Seamos sabios en su uso.

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión @RuslanLópez, leer opiniones diferentes a la mía siempre me ayuda a obtener nuevos enfoques, me parece interesante los ejemplos de los luchadores jeje. ;)